# Is the Fort Bloodlet Throne in Skyrim identical to the Pale Pass Fort?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

Bloodlet Throne is a fortress occupied by vampires in the very south of Skyrim, approximately where there stands "Pale Pass" on the Skyrim map. The landscape there looks extremely similar to the one the Pale Pass Fort is in when you are to retrieve the Madness Stone for countess Narina Carvain. If you conquer Falkreath Hold with the Stormcloaks, there will appear a notice at Fort Neugrad stating

> that there have been avalanches in the Pale Pass which is why it currently can't be reached from Cyrodiil by the Imperial legion.

This explains why you can't just take the serpent's trail to Cyrodiil from the Bloodlet Throne area which I believe is indeed the Pale Pass. It would also explain why there aren't any more Akavíri soldier statues (that was 200 years ago, after all). Other than that, the landscape looks exactly like in the Pale Pass, even the path leading from the fort is there. The fort's interior is different, but so is the interior of Fort Frostmoth on Solstheim, or what the Skaal village looks like, compared to Morrowind Bloodmoon.

Another hint is that the Pale Pass is in Falkreath hold, but if the serpent's trail went straight underground from where it begins in Bruma county, it would end close to Ivarstead in the Rift. Since the Pale Pass Fort *is* in Skyrim, and no other fort is where it is supposed to be, I think they're indeed identical. What is your stance or what do you know about it?

Comment: Hey Jean, just a quick note, you may want to reword your final sentence, since in its current state it reads as asking for our opinion. There's likely more fact to this, so a reword to ask about that would be advised.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I reworded it but I'm unsure if there's an official canon on it. However, given the fact the fort is where "Pale Pass" stands on the map, and there's no other fort that may or may not be it, I guess Bloodlet Throne is the Pale Pass fort. Another hint is that vampires are undead, just like the Akavíri soldiers.